# Bitcoin Core change derivation path with getnewaddress cmd 0.17

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip32-hd-wallets, bitcoin-cli

As I'm building a simple HD wallet, I would like to use bitcoin core regtest. My goal is to setup a testing flow where I could have constant seeded address each time I use `bitcoin-testnet-box`, so that I could cross-check derivated addresses amongst other tests.

Using bitcoin-cli `sethdseed` and `getnewaddress` is the way, but I can't figure a solution to derivate child keys using another path than the default bitcoin core's one which seems to be `m/0'/0'/i'`.

Is there a way to change derivation path in a custom way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Bitcoin Core currently does not allow you to use a different derivation path.